# For which $k$ the following equation has the greatest value: $ k \cdot\binom{99}{k} $?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

After some manipulation I got $$\frac{99!}{(k-1)!\cdot(99-k)!} $$

So I guess I have to find $k$ for which I get the smallest denominator, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Hint: Do you know which if the binomial coefficients $n \choose k$,$0 \le k \le n$ has the greatest value? If yes, can you apply that knowledge for $n=98$ to your problem?

Comment: Try it with $k=25$

Comment: HINT:$$(k+1)\binom{99}{k+1}-(k)\binom{99}{k}=\frac{99!}{(k-1)!(98-k)!}\left(\frac{99-2k}{k(99-k)}\right)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Note that

$$(k+1)\binom{99}{k+1}-(k)\binom{99}{k}=\frac{99!}{(k-1)!(98-k)!}\left(\frac{99-2k}{k(99-k)}\right)$$

Now determine the values of $k$ for which $k\binom{99}{k}$ is increasing and the values of $k$ for which $k\binom{99}{k}$ are decreasing.  Can you conclude now?

Comment: Yes, thank you! It helped a lot

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Set  $a_k=k\,\dbinom{99} k$ and show  the sequence $(a_k)_{0\le k\le 99}$  is first increasing, then decreasing by comparing the ratio $\;\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}$ to $1$. This ratio simplifies to a homographic function of $k$.

Comment: Hello Bernard my friend.  (+1) Yes indeed, it works for quotients and differences too as I showed in my post.  ;-)

Comment: @MarkViola: I wanted to insist on the ratio method (for positive terms). Too many students think only of the difference compared to $0$, and it can lead to terrible calculations, especially for problems of a multiplicative nature.

Comment: In this case, the difference method is tantamount to a "discrete derivative" and one looks for the point where the sequence goes from increasing to decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

$$
k\binom{99}k=99\binom{98}{k-1},
$$
so it suffices to maximize $\binom{98}{k-1}$. The largest binomial coefficient is in the middle, so...